# Add attribute from one List to another List by same Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way yo make this code cleaner, I am trying to copy an attribute of one list to another list when the lists have the same ID.

Thanks for your help.

```
/*Parameters*/
List < Model1 > List1, <Model2 > List2

List < Model1 > newList = new List < Model1 > ();

foreach(Model1 list1 in List1) {
  foreach(Model2 list2 in List2) {
    if (list1.ID == list2.ID) {
      list1.Attribute = list2.Attribute;
    }
  }
  newList.Add(list1);
}
return newList;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to copy an attribute to the same items from list1

```
public static void CopyAttributesOfMatchingItems(List<Model1> list1, List<Model2> list2)
{
        foreach (var item in list1)
        {
            var matchingItem = list2.SingleOrDefault(i2 => i2.Id == item.Id);
            if (matchingItem != null)
                item.Attribute = matchingItem.Attribute;
// if Attribute is reference type, and you want an actual copy you will need to clone... item.Attribute = matchingItem.Attribute.Clone();
        }
}
```

If you need to add the items with matching Ids to a new list (since you've mentioned in the comment that you want to utilize Lambda expression ).

```
public static List<Model1> CopyItemsToNewList(List<Model1> list1, List<Model2> list2)
{
        List<Model1> newList = new List<Model1>();
        newList.AddRange(list1.Where(i1 => list2.Any(i2 => i2.Id == i1.Id) ));
        return newList;
}
```

Note: From the question it's not very clear if you want to add that same object to a new list or if you want an actual copy of the object added to the new list. In case of the former you are good with this, in case of the latter you'll need to use a method to clone that object and add the clone to the list..

Comment: matchingItem is work at my case

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the code you have? If it's already wrapped in a method anyways, I don't see the problem with what you have. I would post a comment instead of an answer, but you need more rep than I have to do so.

You could make it an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) if that makes sense in your context

```
//Put this in a static class
public static List<Model1> CopyAttributes(this List<Model1> list1, List<Model2> list2) {
    List<Model1> newlist = new List<Model1>();
    foreach(Model1 item1 in list1) {
        foreach(Model2 item2 in list2) {
            if(item1.ID == item2.ID) {
                item1.Attribute = item2.Attribute;
            }
        }
        newlist.Add(item1);
    }
    return newlist;
}
```

EDIT: Here is a LINQ solution using lambdas as you asked for; This code isn't the best practice but is what you seem to be asking for. It also isn't much smaller, purely because what you want is unique to your case and can't be generalized much.

```
List<Model1> newlist = new List<Model1>();
list1.ForEach(item1 => {
    list2.ForEach(item2 => {
        if(item1.ID == item2.ID) item1.Attribute = item2.Attribute;
    });
    newlist.Add(item1);
});
```

Comment: I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to copy the attribute maybe using Lambda expressions, or do you think this is the best way ? thanks for your help and regards.

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully that's what you're looking for @Zero